# Whats does this command mean in Unix?

Tags: unix

What does it mean in Unix when you use `. ./<filename>`?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

". ./?" would try and run a program called '?' which would reside in the current directory and it would be run in the current shell.

The first dot means 'run in current shell' (rather than spawning a new one)., the './' means 'current directory' and '?' would mean an executable file called '?' would have to exist.

Comment: Note that a file does not need to be executable to be sourced by `.`. And it must be a shell script (i.e. you can't source a compiled executable).

Answer (score 1):

Running `.` on a filename runs the commands in the file as though you typed them at the shell command prompt.  Unlike a shell script, environment variable (and similar) changes produced by the file persist beyond running the file; the changes made by a shell script are reverted when the script finishes.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` or `source` command reads the given file into the current shell. I.e. basically the given file is a shellscript which is run by typing `. filename`, however using `.` (or `source`, which is equivalent) differs from running the file ordinarily as a shell script in that it doesn't spawn a subshell and thus retains variables that are exported by the script. So if the script sets and exports variables, they will still be set when the script finishes.

Answer (score 0):

`source` or `.` take a file as parameter. Every line of code in that file is executed. So I don't think that

```
. ./
```

would work.

```
$ . ./
-bash: .: ./: is a directory
$ echo "echo Hello" > out
$ . out
Hello
$ source out
Hello
```